# Altium chaning footprint's origin cause shifting on pcb issue

Tags: components, altium, library

I needed to update all of my components in my library (shown in the images below), but when I update my project to new components, all of the components are shifting because of origin change. Is it possible to do some tricks, feature, script to avoid shifting issue?

Thank you for your help!

Old component:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/VZH9neW.jpg]

Updated component:

[image]

Comment: Can you place the origin in the same location as your old footprint on your new one?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this.

Comment: @Colin__s company wants to put origin at middle cause their all components like that. So i have to change my components origin to middle

Comment: If you shift the origin, you can only use the new footprint in new designs. You cannot simply substitute it into existing designs. If you want to modify an existing design and use the new library, you'll have to manually adjust the component placement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the origin information of each component is not stored in the PCB design - only the position of the component origin referenced to the PCB origin. It does not know where the origin is within the component. Somehow the software would need to detect the location of the origins within the original components and the location of the origins within the updated components and shift the components automatically in every PCB design. I suppose it may be possible using a script, but it's probably impractical and an inefficient use of your engineering time to develop the script (unless you're well-versed in the language already).